# Center text in a div with a percentage height

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with a height en width of 33.33%. I want text in the middle of the `div`.

HTML

```
<div class="blogs" id="content">
  <div id="blog1">tests</div>
  <div id="blog2"></div>
  <div id="blog3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#blog1 {
  width: 33.33%;
  padding-bottom: 33.33%;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}
```

[image]
How can i make this?

Comment: Do you mean vertically aligned or horizontally aligned? I assume you mean vertically since you specify height?

Comment: http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this:

**html**

```
<div class="blogs" id="content">
    <div id="blog1">text in the middle
        <span>blog 1</span>
    </div>
   <div id="blog2"><span>blog 2</span></div>
   <div id="blog3"><span>blog 3</span></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
 #blog1{
        width: 33.33%;
        /*padding-bottom: 33.33%;*/
        background: red;
        text-align: center;
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align:middle;
        position: relative;
    }

.blogs > div > span{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
}
 #blog2{
        width: 33.33%;
        padding-bottom: 33.33%;
        background: green;
        text-align: center;
        display:table-cell;
        position: relative;
    }
 #blog3{
        width: 33.33%;
        padding-bottom: 33.33%;
        background: blue;
        text-align: center;
        display:table-cell;
        position: relative;
    }

#content{
    display:table;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntcMT/3/)

And another example with static width e.g. `500px` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntcMT/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FAVX5/)**.

Just set `height` and `line-height` equal and add `vertical-align:middle;`

Your code will look like this:

```
#blog1{
    width: 33.33%;
    height:300px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:300px; /* has to bee the same value as the height of the div */
}
```

Comment: The width and the hight must be 33.33%

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="blogs" id="content">
   <div id="blog1">tests</div>
   <div id="blog2"></div>
   <div id="blog3"></div>

   <!-- You need to add this after the last <div> -->
   <div style="clear:right;"></div>
</div>

#blog1, #blog2, #blog3 {
   float:left;
   padding: 3% 0;
   background: red;
   width: 100px;
   height:100%;
   text-align:center;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xaA2Y/4/)

Comment: The width and the hight must be 33.33%

Comment: You want them to be one third of the size of the #content div? Editing the sizes of the blog divs is the easiest part. The part about addressing the text being in the center was answered though.